# SQL, Basic Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a lab for my database class that is using the Northwind Data base in SQL. A few of the questions I can't seem to figure out are

> List the name of all products where the unit price is greater than the
>   average unit price.

I would assume it would look something like

```
Select Product Name From Products Where UnitPrice > AVG(UnitPrice)
```

It doesn't seem to accept this though.

Also, another question is

> List the name of the product with the lowest unit price

I assumed it would be

```
Select ProductName From Product Where MIN(UnitPrice)
```

None of these are working and I'm getting extremely frustrated, please help!

Comment: `Product Name` or `Product_Name` or `ProductName`?

Comment: The `WHERE` condition always compares two values

Answer (score 2):

You can't put group functions into the WHERE clause. Think of it this way: the expression in the WHERE clause must reference only one row of the table (or the join of rows from more than one table). But the expression can't take into account a group of rows.

Instead, you can use a subquery to get the average price:

```
Select p.ProductName 
From Products As p
Cross Join (Select AVG(UnitPrice) AS avg_unit_price From Products) As a
Where p.UnitPrice > a.avg_unit_price
```

Comment: This produces a syntax error as you have no join conditions. Presumably you meant a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @KyleHale, yes thanks for that catch. I'm so used to using MySQL, and it's permitted to omit the join condition in MySQL. Question was tagged only with `sql` so I shouldn't assume which RDBMS brand or version.

Comment: The hint for me was the reference to the Northwind database, which is a Microsoft thing. : )

Answer (score 1):

List the name of all products where the unit price is greater than the average unit price:

```
Select p.ProductName 
       From Products p
       Where p.UnitPrice > (Select AVG(UnitPrice) From Products)
```

List the name of the product with the lowest unit price:
(Returns all products having least UnitPrice)

```
Select p.ProductName 
       From Products p
       Where p.UnitPrice = (Select MIN(UnitPrice) From Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.[Product Name]
From Products a, (select AVG(UnitPrice) as AvgUnitPrice from Products) b
Where a.UnitPrice > b.AvgUnitPrice
```

or

```
Select a.[Product Name]
From Products a
Where a.UnitPrice > (select AVG(UnitPrice) as AvgUnitPrice from Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Avg Decimal
Select  @Avg = Sum(UnitPrice) / Count(UnitPrice)
        From Products

Select A.ProductName
       From Products
       Where UnitPrice > @Avg
```